# Android splash-screen status bar background color change to blue and text black

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen, background-color, statusbar

I have implemented a splash screen in native Android for my react-native code, I need to set the status bar color of the splash screen to blue and the font color of the status bar to black,

I have implemented some code but it is not working for all android devices.

let me know if anyone has any idea about how to achieve this.